# Ways to redirect http:// to https://

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal-8, httpd.conf

We have a Drupal 8 application hosted on Ubuntu server with Apache, PHP 5.6 and MySQL 5.6. I want to know in howmany ways can we redirect domain from http:// to https:// protocol.

I have tried following ways

1. From virtual host configuration file using redirect.
2. Enabled rewrite rule and provided redirect condition in .htaccess file of the project.

When I use above approaches the site is getting down when number of requests increased. If I remove the redirect conditions the site is working fine even when more requests come to the server.

So, I want to know are there any other ways to redirect domain from http:// to https:// protocol without burden on the server.

Comment: Are you using `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directives? The latter enables regex processing and is not always necessary. And you should also disable default https check in htaccess

Comment: I'm using Redirect @msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Configure mod_rewrite in your httpd.conf to achieve such a redirect

For example:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module  modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
LoadModule rewrite_module  modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

or

```
LoadModule rewrite_module  modules/mod_rewrite.so
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```